# Does \frenchspacing make \@ redundant?

Tags: frenchspacing

In TeX/LaTeX's default mode, there is extra space after sentence-ending periods, which needs to be suppressed with `\@.` when TeX would mistakenly treat it as ending a sentence, as in `Mr\@. Bean`. While `\frenchspacing` eliminates the (nominally) double space between sentences, I wonder if sentence-ending periods are nevertheless treated differently from abbreviation periods (e.g., when stretching spaces, computing penalties, or whatever).

In other words: If I use `\frenchspacing` (and will never format my text without it), is there any point to writing `\@.`?

Comment: Hmm, indeed it's a duplicate! Thanks. Somehow the linked question didn't come up when I searched, but it addresses my question (and the converse, which I wasn't worried about).

Comment: Just a note: the `\@` does *not* suppress the extra space but actually enforces it AFAIK. You would write `Mr.\ Bean` to suppress it.